# R Shiny echarts4r Map Zoom

Tags: r, shiny, echarts, echarts4r

I'm able to load up successfully R Shiny map using [echarts4r](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/) library.  I'm looking to add a simple zoom for users to zoom in and out.

I have added function to zoom, and it shows up on the Map (in the upper right hand corner), but when I attempt to use, it does not actually do any sort of zoom.  Suggestions?

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)
library(echarts4r.maps)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
      echarts4rOutput("map")
    ))

# server.R
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)
library(echarts4r.maps)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$map <- echarts4r::renderEcharts4r({
  ca <- e_charts() %>%
  em_map("Canada") %>% 
  e_map(map = "Canada") %>%
  e_datazoom()
})
  
})
```

[image: shiny app output]